# Help me style a form with css

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/R9ejR/

I want to display some of the fields like `height`, `weight`, `physique`, e.t.c to show side-by-side, so I wrote a simple css `showOnSide`, which simply `float:left` the content, but when I add this class after an `formelement`, the element becomes unclickable. Any ideas?

Comment: None of the elements in your jsfiddle have the `showOnSide` class.  Please give us an example that is not working instead of making us construct a non-working case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the position:relative, then remove that. (thanks Maus).

Otherwise:

Solution in jsFiddle: 
[Solution with clear and floats](http://jsfiddle.net/R9ejR/4/)

It is hard to explain, but your li element after the floated one was sitting on top of your input element. Now the floating works as expected. Clearing is needed to force the listitems without ShowOnSide beneath the floats.

Comment: It's hard to explain because it's actually wrong. First of all, you're double clearing the items (once themselves, then in the :after). Second, only `.showOnSide` should have `position: relative`, not every `form li`.

Answer (score 1):

Classes have to be separated by a single space, like `li class="form_element showOnSide"`

Comment: Yeh I did that, but the element cannot be clicked after adding `showOnSide` . try clicking on the `height` input box http://jsfiddle.net/R9ejR/3/

Comment: Drop `position: relative;` for the `form li`